# WPF: TwoWay Binding doesn't update back

Tags: wpf, two-way-binding

I have the following custom control:

```
<abc:MyControl MyProperty="{Binding FieldInMyModel, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

And in my custom control I have

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(double), typeof(MyControl),
     new PropertyMetadata(0.0, OnMyPropertyChanged));

public double MyProperty
{
     get { return (double)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty ); }
     set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty , value); }
}

private static void OnMyPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, 
     DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
     if (d is MyControl mc)
     {
          // here I check if the new value is valid for my scope.
          // if it is not I update it here to be valid
          var v = (double)e.NewValue;
          if (!mc.IsValidValue(v))
          {
               v = mc.MakeValidValue(v);
               mc.MyProperty = v;
          }
     }
}
```

In my model I change the value of `FieldInMyModel` to be not valid for my scope. `OnMyPropertyChanged` is called, and after making a valid value from received invalid value I expect that the `FieldInMyModel` will be updated to have the new value of `MyProperty` but actually nothing happens. Any thought?

Comment: Have you considered using a [CoerceValueCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.coercevaluecallback?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: Do you expect the validated, i.e. new property value to be passed back to the view model while the view model is currently updating its FieldInMyModel property?

Comment: @Clemens yes, that is exactly what I want. btw, coerceValueCallback also didn't work for it.

Comment: Afaik this will not work, because the framework is not designed to pass a value back to a binding source while this source is currently changing. You may try to do this asynchronously somehow.

Comment: Yea, this was what I also was thinking of and afraid of at the same time :) . Will try to workaround by introducing a new property instead and do the validation in the model before passing it to my control. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Setting `MyProperty` from code will break your TwoWay Binding.

Instead you can use `SetCurrentValue` method.

Comment: While setting a new local value for a dependency property replaces a previously set OneWay Binding, this is not true for TwoWay Bindings.

Comment: `SetCurrentValue` doesn't help eaither.